# Fill entire container with an image without leaving blank spaces

Tags: flutter

I have this grid view item:

[image]

As you can see, the image isn't filling all the container (green area). I would like to fill it all; in other words, there would be no green color.

This is the code for the container:

```
                 Container(
                                width: width,
                                alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                                child: Container(
                                  // padding: EdgeInsets.all(4),
                                  
                                  width: width * 0.2,
                                  decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                                    color: Colors.green,
                                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                                      topRight: Radius.circular(10),
                                      bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
                                      topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
                                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
                                      
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                  child: Image.network(output['image'],
                                  fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                       loadingBuilder:
                                          (context, child,
                                              loadingProgress) {
                                    if (loadingProgress == null) {
                                      return child;
                                    } else {
                                      return const Center(
                                          child: CircularProgressIndicator(
                                              valueColor:
                                                  AlwaysStoppedAnimation<
                                                          Color>(
                                                      Colors.white)));
                                    }
                                  }),
                                ),
                              ),
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I noticed is that your image is circular and the container is a square with border radius:

[image]

The way I was able to get it to not show the background is by scaling the image and clipping the edges, like:

```dart
   ClipRRect(
     borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
        topRight: Radius.circular(10),
         bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
         topLeft: Radius.circular(45),
         bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10),
     ),
     child: Container(
       width: 150,
       height: 150,
       child: Transform.scale(
         scale: 2,
         child: Image.network(output['image'])
       )
    )
)
```

Which makes it show like this:

[image]

Comment: doesn't work...

Comment: Sorry, I meant to also put that you use the **Container**'s **DecorationImage** and then use **BoxFit.cover**. I will update my answer

Answer (score 1):

Try this,replacing your width with `MediaQuery`

```
Container(
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
  
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    image: DecorationImage(
      fit: BoxFit.fill,
      image: NetworkImage("image"),
    ),
  ),
)
```